# With RingCT, could an adversary get into a bunch of ring signatures to decrease privacy?

Tags: ringct, privacy, ring-signatures, attack, spam-attack

Let's say I want to deanonymize Monero. What if I create a ton of RingCT outputs, such that, say, +99% of them are mine. Since amounts don't matter with RingCT, it can be very small amounts (like one atomic unit each).

Now if in a ring signature, 4 of public keys are mine, and I didn't sign it, I know that it must have been the other public key. In this way, I can link addresses on the block chain, and do block chain analysis.

Is there something preventing this attack?

Comment: @user36303 I think ringct adds a new twist since you don't need to control much monero.

Comment: You need as much, given the estimation relies on tx fees.

Comment: @PyRulez maybe you could make a question based on the comment of 36303.... Given the estimates for tx fees would a spam attack to obtain outputs in attempt to undermine privacy be more of less expensive after the arrival of RIngCT?